# Link a repository folder to another non-repo folder

Tags: git, github, filesystems

I have local windows machine which I use as a local dev environment.
Which has a project directory as follows.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs
 |-project1
 |-project2
```

I also use what Github/AWS code deployment. Which basically is repo I have that when I publish changes, it deploys the changes to the server.

However the structure of the repo files is a bit different. This is how its structured locally on my computer.

```
..\Github
     |-repository
        |-folder1
        |-folder2
        |-project2
        |-some other files
```

So the project that is associated in this repository is **project2** which contatins the websites files of my server (hence the reason its at the htdocs folder). Currently the way I make changes is:

- do them at htdocs
- then copy all changes to the repo folder

which is tedious if you have alot of changes.
I then came across symbolic links to link the ***htdocs/project2*** and ***repository/project2***, which unfortunately are unsupported in git.

So is there way to link them, or maybe a way to tell git to use the ***htdocs\ project2*** folder as its **project2** folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really link a folder using git - that is more of a OS thing - probably if you where using linux the sym-links would work better.

However, if project2 is some sort of common repo (i.e. its going to be used in more than one place) you could make it a separate repository and then add it to your github/repository as a sub-module.

Then git clone your project2 repo into htdocs (not as a submodule, but as a normal repo).

Now when you make changes to htdocs/project2 you can push them to the remote (in github). When you are happy with your changes you update your github/repository (which has the submodule preject2 in it) to point to the latest project2 commit. Then your AWS will automatically deploy as before with the updated project2.

This would probably be the correct "workflow" for this sort of work...

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach with symlinks could work. You can make a link from htdocs/project2 -> to repository/project2. On Windows this can be done with [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink).

I would instead align the 2 structures. Because your local XAMPP configuration is under your full control, you could just configure Apache so that your DocumentRoot points to your ...\Github\repository folder instead of C:\xampp\htdocs . Then you can work and commit to the same place without copying.

Comment: Why it is not trivial on Windows? Just `mklink /J link target`

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know.

So something like:

 mklink /J C:\xampp\htdocs\project2 ...\Github\repository\project2 

should work then.
Might also need to set FollowSymLinks in Apache config?